# playable ad. how to fix control offset due to screen scaling?

Tags: javascript

In my playable ad, the following scaling system is implemented:

```
  var scallingec = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight
  var scallinggame = canvas.width/canvas.height
  if(scallingec>scallinggame){
  canvas.style.height='100vh'
  canvas.style.width=''
}else{
  canvas.style.width='100vw'
  canvas.style.height=''
}
```

there are no problems with scaling, but with control, when the scale of the canvas changes, the touchpad stops working correctly

```
function handleStart(e) {
        if(e.touches) {
touch.state=true

touch.y=e.touches[0].pageY
touch.x=e.touches[0].pageX



        }else{
        touch.state=false
        }
        }
```

since e.touches[0].pageX, and e.touches[0].pageY , needs additional adjustments in terms of scale. I tried many ways to implement this, but there is no one formula for all sizes. Are there any ideas how this can be implemented, or how it is done in other projects.